# Getting Status Code 499 on GET requests from my AWS Cloud9 runner

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, p5.js, aws-cloud9

I've been adjusting my workflow to the new AWS version of Cloud9 for a few weeks now, it's been going mostly smooth, but I hit a strange issue that I can't find any documentation on.

Whenever I try to send a GET request from the client side JavaScript, like most recently, to load in a JSON file from the public directory, I get an HTTP Error with a status code 499 ()

The primary thing I am trying to get running is a static page that loads in some JSON and renders the data in the canvas. Now, I was able to use a workaround where I just put the JSON in a separate JS file and made it a global variable instead, but that's not really Ideal.

Here are some of the specifics.
AWS Cloud9 server
create-react-app web server
P5.js library for clientside js
The JSON file in question is stored in a subdirectory of the index.html

Here's the kicker, when I publish the code to a test Production server the code works fine, this makes me think its got to be a setting in the cloud9 environment that's at fault

Error:
p5.js:59833 GET https://9560a28022cd45e1a8d25f94fa86507c.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/js/json/StarData2.json 499 ()
p5.httpDo @ p5.js:59833
p5.loadJSON @ p5.js:58944
(anonymous) @ p5.js:46182
preload @ sketch.js:6
(anonymous) @ p5.js:46147
p5 @ p5.js:46434
_globalInit @ p5.js:48404
load (async)
26.../core/core @ p5.js:48413
s @ p5.js:2
(anonymous) @ p5.js:2
13../color/creating_reading @ p5.js:42088
s @ p5.js:2
e @ p5.js:2
(anonymous) @ p5.js:2
(anonymous) @ p5.js:2
(anonymous) @ p5.js:2

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with AWS Cloud9 running Django development server on port 8081 and angular development server (ng serve) on standard port ($PORT). Both django and angular are working independently (can display webpages) however error 499 is returned when angular frontend tries to load backend data (JSON GET requests).

**I am sharing my solution here :**

BACKEND (DJANGO)

```
source venv/bin/activate
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081
```

The backend can be accessed at http://IP:8081/

FRONTEND (ANGULAR)

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disable-host-check
```

The frontend can be accessed at http://IP:8080/

Where IP is the AWS instance IP that can be checked by clicking on the Share button on the upper right corner of Cloud9 workspace.